# Bleichenbacher RSA1024 signature forgery, closed-form solution

Tags: rsa, attack

Hal Finney's writeup ([Bleichenbacher's RSA signature forgery based on implementation error](https://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/openpgp/current/msg00999.html)) shows a formula for RSA3072. I tried to replicate the attack for RSA1024 and failed, since the first term of the equation `2^1009` is not a perfect cube. I ended up forging a signature by simply constructing a desired number and taking cube root of it. But I'm curious, is it possible to come up with a clean formula, as in the case of RSA3072?

Answer (score 2):

If I correctly understood [Izu, Tetsuya et al. “Extending Bleichenbacher's Forgery Attack.” J. Inf. Process. 16 (2008): 122-129](https://ipsj.ixsq.nii.ac.jp/ej/?action=repository_action_common_download&item_id=9429&item_no=1&attribute_id=1&file_no=1), then analytical solution is impossible for RSA1024 both regarding size of the key, and it's divisibility by 3. They use *|n|* for the key length.

> ...Bleichenbacher’s attack with e = 3 is applicable to the case with
> |n| ≥ 1,739 with |n| is divisible by 3. More precisely, |n| can be parameterized
> by |n| = 3k for k ≥ 580...

Btw, further in the article they provide computational attack algorithm which uses message tweaking and works for wider spectrum of parameters.

Also it should be noted, that cited conclusion is given for SHA-1 message hashing and numbers will deviate depending on length of hash of used hashing method and length of it's ASN.1 identifier.